# Magento 2 : Error when i click the admin->configuration

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2.2, system-config

I am getting this error when I click on `stores->configuration`

> Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\tork\vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator.php on line 63

I tried to disable custom modules which has config section.Still get the same error.

**Is there any way to check from which module I am getting this issue?**

Comment: Did you install which module ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend you to use the xDebug to easily detect which element has no id:

[image: example of xdebug]

In case you are working on the remote server on which you can not install xDebug you can use the `var_dump()` with condition like:

```
if (count($elements)) {
    $lastElement = end($elements);
    if (empty($lastElement['id'])) {
        var_dump($elements);
        var_dump($lastElement);
    }
    $this->_lastId = $lastElement['id'];
}
```

in the `magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php` (inside the `setElements()` method). Then using indirect signs you be able to detect which element from the config tree causes problems.